# Apply the same random shuffle on multiple containers

Tags: c++, sorting

I am writing a program where a Manager-class handles different containers.
Every container is the same size with the same contents and needs to be (randomly) shuffled the same way.
(FYI, The program will later apply different operations on each container)

What I want to achieve:
Randomly sort each container, but all containers has to be sorted the same way, **without** copying a container. I do not want to copy because the contents of each container is not just integers and would thus be very expensive.

Therefore, I do **not** seek a solution like the one that follows:

```
void ContainerMgr::Shuffle()
{
    std::random_shuffle(m_tmp.begin(), m_tmp.end());

    for (auto &subContainer : m_allContainers)
        subContainer = m_tmp;
}
```

My question:
Does C++ (perhaps STL) provide a way to *randomly* shuffle, let's say 5, different (equally sized) containers in the same way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it necessary to shuffle the containers themselves, or could you live with a shuffled array of indexes into the containers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `std::random_shuffle` before it ws removed and it's replacement, `std::shuffle`, support passing to them a pseudo-random number generator.  You *should* be able to leverage that to pass "the same" generator to each invocation to of the shuffler so that it shuffles in the same manner.

I say *should* here because the implementation of the shuffling algorithms is pretty vauge and all we really have is [[alg.random.shuffle]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/alg.random.shuffle#5) which has

> *Remarks:* To the extent that the implementation of this function makes use of random numbers, the object referenced by g shall serve as the implementation's source of randomness.

I believe that remark means that two identical PRNG's pass to two different invocations should produce the same result since they would have the same randomness

That would give you code like

```
void ContainerMgr::Shuffle()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 g(rd()); // set a random seed

    for (auto &subContainer : m_allContainers)
    {
        auto g_copy = g;
        std::shuffle(subContainer.begin(), subContainer.end(), g_copy); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) provides zip view that you can then shuffle.

```
auto zip_view = ranges::view::zip(v1, v2, v3);

std::mt19937 rnd(std::random_device{});
std::shuffle(zip_view.begin(), zip_view.end(), rnd);
```

Else, without library, you might create an array of indexes, shuffle it, and access your array with that indirection:

```
std::vector<std::size_t> indexes(v1.size());
std::iota(indexes.begin(), indexes.end(), 0);

std::mt19937 rnd(std::random_device{});
std::shuffle(indexes.begin(), indexes.end(), rnd);

std::size_t i = 42;
f(v1[indexes[i]], v2[indexes[i]], v3[indexes[i]]);
```

Comment: An array of indicies would be (for this specific small project I was doing) more feasible. Thanks for the suggestion!